# FCN training in 1 epoch?

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm training an FCN, specifically tiramisu, on a large dataset of 700 000 images of 224x224.  I'm not using augmentation and I'm using batches of 5. What I find odd and counter-intuitive is that the training seems to be too fast.  I get validation accuracies in excess of 97% with validation losses below 0.02 after 1-2 epochs.  And then the model starts overfitting with the validation scores slowly degrading, sometimes with a bit of oscillations (but no nans).  My objects are small and I have a lot of background, so I know 97% is potentially not as good as you might think.  I've tried quite a few permutations of base learning rates with a learning scheduler with different rates of decay, but the behaviour is similar.  Is it even possible for an FCN to train so fast?  Or is there something fundamentally wrong with my setup?

Comment: I’d start by looking for bugs in my code.

Comment: i don't think it's out of the ordinary to see convergence within 1 epoch

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. If I actually look at some tiles in the validation set, the predictions look excellent.